# Multiple Div Jquery Animated Hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a few nested divs with different articles in them.

```
<div id="maindiv" onmouseover="showbuttons()" onmouseout="hidebuttons()">
    <div style="float: left"></div>
    <div style="float: right">
         <div id="buttons"></div>
    </div>
</div>

function show() {
    $('#buttons').slideDown('fast')
    //$('#buttons').stop().slideDown('fast')

}

function hide() {
    $('#buttons').slideUp('fast')
    //$('#buttons').stop().slideUp('fast')

}
```

The problem is I think the hover event gets fired a couple of times so I keep having the buttons disappear and reappear. So I added `stop()` - Which is commented in the code above. But then I have buttons half way through the page (due to the cancelled animation) when I have the mouse leave.

Or perhaps theres a way to do this in CSS?

Comment: Hiya man seems working here: http://jsfiddle.net/Zarhu/1/ let me know if this helps and want me to set up as answer! B-)

Comment: It seems to have the same problem, move the mouse in the div but off and back on the button div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` attributes from the `div` and replace your javascript with:

```
$('#maindiv').hover(
    function() {
        $('#buttons').stop().slideDown('fast');
    },
    function() {
        $('#buttons').stop().slideUp('fast');
    }
);
```

Comment: "onmouseenter is IE-specific. Doesn't work in other browsers unless you use jQuery which can simulate this event."
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1638929/246260

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should do something like:

```
$('#maindiv').hover(function() {
    $('#buttons').stop().slideDown('fast')
}, function() {
    $('#buttons').stop().slideUp('fast')
})
```

It's cleaner and simple.

Answer (score 0):

for starts,

```
 show()
```

is already used by jquery so for sanity avoid that name

remove the event listener from being inline with the markup ..

```
  $("#maindiv").mouseover( function() {
    $("#buttons").stop(true, true).slideUp();
   });

  $("#maindiv").mouseout( function() {
    $("#buttons").stop(true, true).slideDown();
   });
```

look into the toggle function too

Comment: I only used show for the sake of the simplified code example, thanks