# How to detect mousein and mouseleave in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I can't use jQuery for this part of the project due to various reasons. SO I need to detect this in vanilla js. I tried this but it doesn't work:

http://jsfiddle.net/qHfJD/

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('foo');

myDiv.onmouseenter = function() { 
    alert('entered');
}

myDiv.onmouseleave = function() { 
    alert('left');
}
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638877/difference-between-onmouseover-and-onmouseenter) may help explain the difference between the events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are proprietary MS events (that are actually pretty nice).  If `myDiv` has no children, using `mouseover` / `mouseout` will have exactly the same effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/qHfJD/1/

**Note:** this original question and answer were very old and from a time when `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` were not well supported outside of IE. All modern browsers have supported these events on elements for quite some time now. They are generally preferred over `mouseover`/`mouseout` because the latter will trigger for each child of the element with the event listener in addition to the element itself.

Comment: this does not answer the question, which specified mouse "in" and "leave". Mouseover executes multiple times on elements that contain children. The closest answer I believe was given by ride on Feb 3rd.

Answer (score 5):

```
myDiv.onmouseover = function(event) {
  if (this != event.currentTarget) { return false; }
  // mouse enter ...
}
myDiv.onmouseout = function(event) {
  if (this != event.currentTarget) { return false; }
  // mouse leave ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events are proprietary to Internet Explorer, so if you aren't using IE, they won't work. Use `mouseover` and `mouseout`, instead.

By the way, you can use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` via jQuery because jQuery simulates those events for you on non-IE browsers. See [this article](http://blog.stchur.com/2007/03/15/mouseenter-and-mouseleave-events-for-firefox-and-other-non-ie-browsers/) for tips on how to simulate `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` for yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You are close. The function name is onmouseover and onmouseout

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('foo');

myDiv.onmouseover = function() { 
  alert('entered');
}

myDiv.onmouseout = function() { 
  alert('left');
}
```

Comment: mouseover and mouseenter are two different things.

Answer (score -2):

Try: 
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('foo');

```
myDiv.onmouseover = function() { 
    alert('entered');
}

myDiv.onmouseout = function() { 
    alert('left');
}
```

onmouseenter and onmouseleave are IE-only functionality.