# onMouseLeave/onMouseOut sometimes triggered on page refresh React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-animations, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have an image and when i put the mouse on it, onMouseOver event is triggered and an animation appears. Then when i leave the mouse from image the animation ends.

Here is a fragment of my code, i'm using React and Mozilla Firefox:

```
<img className={classNameDefine('presentation__image')}    
    onMouseOver={() => {
       handleAnimation('animationA')
    }} 
    onMouseLeave={() => {
       handleAnimation('animationA')
    }}
src={logo} alt="s"/>
```

**The issue** is that sometimes when i refresh page and put mouse on the image it works well, but other times on refresh the onMouseLeave event it triggered for no reason and breaks my animation.

I tried using onMouseEnter intead of onMouseOver and onMouseOut instead of onMouseLeave, but the same problem occours.

Why sometimes it works well but in others times not?

**PD:** I tried by using another navigator like Chrome and Edge, and the mouse events works fine without bugs. Now i don't know if there is a problem between Mozilla (navegator i am using) and React. Only on mozilla the issue appears.

Comment: Does this explain it ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638877/difference-between-onmouseover-and-onmouseenter

Better to stick with CSS for animation if it's possible.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Like i said, using onMouseOver or onMouseEnter the same problem appears. On the other hand, i'm already been using CSS for animation. The handleAnimation function basically puts an ".active" on a className and a few styles with transition appears. Thanks for the suggestion anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any kind of **state** instant of **Ref**.
If you are using state then it Re-Renders the page and that's why it is breaking your animation.

Comment: Yeah i'm using state but anyways, why it sometimes works well on page refresh and in others not?